# Running a web app full screen on Fire HD 10 tablet

Tags: browser

I have a Fire HD 10 tablet that I recently purchased. I want to run a web app on it in full-screen mode ([this web app, if you're curious](https://github.com/kerrickstaley/transit-panel/)), so that neither the system UI (notifications bar and navigation bar) or the browser UI (address bar) are visible. What Android app can I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I control the web app in this case, I was able to add a button that calls [`document.body.requestFullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen), which works in Chromium, Firefox, and the stock browser (Silk Browser).

It would still be good to get an answer for the case where you can't control the web app.